# Prime number generator between 2 nums

Tags: java, algorithm

I cant figure out which test cases the code provided below fails.
problem:

All submissions for this problem are available.

Shridhar wants to generate some prime numbers for his cryptosystem. Help him!
Your task is to generate all prime numbers between two given numbers.
Input

The first line contains t, the number of test cases (less then or equal to 10).

Followed by t lines which contain two numbers m and n (1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space.
Output

For every test case print all prime numbers p such that m <= p <= n,
one number per line. Separate the answers for each test case by an empty line.
Example

```
Input:
2
1 10
3 5
```

```
Output:
2
3
5
7

3
5
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Main().run();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Integer d;
        try {
            d = sc.nextInt();
            boolean isPrime[] = new boolean[100000];
            for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
                int m = sc.nextInt();
                int n = sc.nextInt();
                if (n <= 0 || m > n) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (m <= 0) {
                    m = 2;
                    if (m > n) {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                if (m == 1) {
                    m = 2;
                }
                if (m == 2 && n - m == 0) {
                    System.out.println(2);
                } else {
                    for (int k = 0; k <= n - m; k++) {
                        isPrime[k] = true;
                    }
                    int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
                    for (int j = 2; j <= sqrt; j++) {
                        int k = (m % j == 0) ? m / j : (m + j) / j;
                        for (; k <= n / j; k++) {
                            if (!(m == 2 && (j * k == 2)) && k != 1) {
                                isPrime[j * k - m] = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    for (int a = m; a <= n; a++) {
                        if (isPrime[a - m]) {
                            System.out.println(a);
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            sc.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is look like a Homework :D

Comment: From the Help Center: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: Its a codechef problem not homework.  It is failing some test case when i try to submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with this:

```
boolean isPrime[] = new boolean[100000];
```

and this:

```
for (int k = 0; k <= n - m; k++) {
   isPrime[k] = true;
}
```

because some time `n - m = 100000` then you need `isPrime[100000]` which you didnt allocate so you need to declare isPrime like this:

```
boolean isPrime[] = new boolean[100001];
```